# Why does Column height calculation break when it contains an element of full width?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt5.4

I'd love to know why the `Column` height calculation breaks when the `Row` spans over the full width.

Toggle the comment, in the following code, to reproduce:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Column {
        id: col
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }

        Row {
            id: row
            anchors {
                left: parent.left
//                right: parent.right
            }

            Rectangle {
                color: "green"
                width: 20
                height: 20
            }

            Rectangle {
                color: "red"
                width: 30
                height: 30
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("col.height: " + col.height)
        console.log("col.implicitHeight: " + col.implicitHeight)
        console.log("col.width: " + col.width)
        console.log("col.implicitWidth: " + col.implicitWidth)
        console.log("row.height: " + row.height)
        console.log("row.implicitHeight: " + row.implicitHeight)
        console.log("row.width: " + row.width)
        console.log("row.implicitWidth: " + row.implicitWidth)
    }
}
```

Case 1 (as above):

```
col.height: 30
col.implicitHeight: 30
col.width: 0
col.implicitWidth: 50
row.height: 30
row.implicitHeight: 30
row.width: 50
row.implicitWidth: 50
```

Case 2 (`Row` spans full width):

```
col.height: 0
col.implicitHeight: 0
col.width: 0
col.implicitWidth: 0
row.height: 30
row.implicitHeight: 30
row.width: 0
row.implicitWidth: 50
```

Comment: For me it says `col.height` and  `col.implicitHeight` is 30, `col.width` and `col.implicitWidth` is 640, `row.height` and `row.implicitHeight` is 30, `row.width` is 640 and `row.implicitWidth` is 50. Tested on Mac 10.10.3 with Qt 5.4 with the anchors of `row` set to parent's left/right

Comment: Interesting. I can reproduce the behavior above on Ubuntu and Windows using Qt 5.4.2. In no case I get `col.implicitWidth/width` of 640. It's either 0 or 50.

Comment: Thanks @qCring for your hint. I can reproduce the correct behavior on OS X. So I think it's a bug then.

Comment: What version/os? On my Mac I've the very same result as Simon but I have OSX 10.10.4 with Qt 5.4.2 installed @qCring.